# How do you configure an emailAdapter for parse-server?

Tags: parse-platform, passwords, reset, mailgun, parse-server

I'm trying to test out the password reset flow on a locally running parse-server instance. Every time I send a password reset request I get the following error `error: Uncaught internal server error. Trying to send a reset password but no adapter is set undefined`. I know I'm supposed to configure the emailAdapter in cli-definitions but I'm not too sure what exactly I'm supposed to put there. I tried changing the contructor in ParseServer.js to have

```
    emailAdapter: {
    module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',
    options: {
      // The address that your emails come from
      fromAddress: 'parse@example.com',
      // Your domain from mailgun.com
      domain: 'example.com',
      // Your API key from mailgun.com
      apiKey: 'key-mykey',
    }
  }
```

but that did not work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just got this configured myself and I think you may just be missing a few parameters.

In the configuration in your index.js or other file where ParseServer is being initialized, you need all of the following:

```
 verifyUserEmails: true,
 // Same as the SERVER_URL used to configure ParseServer, in my case it uses Heroku
 publicServerURL: 'http://MY_HEROKU_APP.herokuapp.com/parse', 
 appName: 'MY_APP',
 emailAdapter: {
    module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',
    options: {
      fromAddress: 'no-reply@example.com',
      domain: 'example.com',
      apiKey: 'key-XXXXXX',
    }
 }
```

Comment: the publicServerUrl being the same as the SERVER_URL is what my problem was, I believe. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, James, where  you added this code? When I add this, my app is not working, not receiving any data. Can you help?

Comment: index.js file. It is added under the var parseConfig = {

Comment: quick question, this api key is public key or private key?